# Pass touch events to one of multiple options

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitouch

I've created a board of UIImageViews, that are held within a single object as an NSArray. all the imageviews are displayed as subviews of the 'board'(the object that holds the array). What I would like to do is when I touch any of the individual squares of the board (the imageviews) that the one that is touched is the one that picks up the event. Currently the board picks up all the touch events. passing the touches automatically to nextResponder doesn't work, since there isn't a single nextResponder, but many, with a single one being the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `UIImageView` overrides the value of the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO` (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/userInteractionEnabled).  This is what is causing your `UIImageViews` to not receive touch events, and so they are accepted by the board superview.

To make it so your `UIImageViews` receive touch events, just set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES`.

Comment: I think you meant to set it to YES, but that did it! Thanks!